# Using Robocopy for file rotation

Tags: windows, file-management, robocopy

I am looking for a way to use robocopy to rotate log files.  Currently I have a batch file using robocopy to copy files and log the results to a specified folder location.  What I would like to do is keep 7 days and on the 8th day drop one off.  Is this possible or should I create another batch file to do this and call it from the original batch file?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a batch file, then it can delete older files in the log-files directory.

Here are two references:

[ForFiles - delete old files, etc.](http://winhlp.com/node/180)
Describes using the forfiles utility for deleting older files.

[batch file to delete files older than a specified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324267/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-a-specified-date)
Is a stackoverflow question that addresses your question here.

Comment: Thanks harrymc....I chose the use teh forfiles reference.  It looks as if it will work well.

Comment: +1, I found out about this not too long ago and love it! I use it all over the place in my batch files. This is how I use it: forfiles /p "E:\Office Backups\Some Folder" /d -6 /c "CMD /C del @FILE"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following script:

```
set checklogcmd=robocopy /s /mov /create /minage:30 /r:0 /w:0
echo ### Checking Logfiles...
%checklogcmd% E:\LOGFILES E:\GARBAGE
rd E:\Garbage /s /q
```

Answer (score 1):

What about syncing all files older than 30 days with an empty folder? I have used this with the purge command to delete with some success.

This example just delete all items from the target folder. With a little editing, it would do it based on a date.

> robocopy.exe "B:\tb1\St-Cloud\EmptyFolder" "B:\St-Cloud\Daily\Fri" /E /PURGE

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Bit ugly, but it works. No real reason to use robocopy, as opposed to just a straight copy. This assumes your logfile is in a standard place, of course.

`del logfile.7`

`robocopy logfile.6 logfile.7`

`robocopy logfile.5 logfile.6`

....

`robocopy logfile logfile.1`

`del logfile`